# How could I only show the min in MS Access?

Tags: database, ms-access

I am very new to access.

I tried to filter the data by using Totals and grouped the productPrice by min, however I get a range of all the product prices from min to max, here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08Tkz.png).

Also there is another column after MinOfproductPrice called storeName, I didn't include it for privacy reasons.

**How could I make it so only the lowest price per product is shown?** An example of what I am trying to [do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmoUt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do a summary query and do a group by with min (as you have done), but I suspect that the column you removed is to blame as it sounds like you want to be able to show that information as well.

There are a few ways to do this. In the first, you'll need to first create a summary query that gets just the product id and minimum price.  Then, link this query back to your main table/query to get the additional columns like store, container, etc.

It is similar to finding just the most recent order row for each of your customers. The technique is the same.  You can see a demo here:
https://youtu.be/5cnwHyn4dnI

Comment: The queries within a query solved my issue, thank you!